# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 15

Tags: javascript, json

I have the Json data , which I am trying to parse in the following fiddle

but its throwing error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 15

I am unable to paste the json here due to the large size kindly follow the fiddle

```
var varArray = JSON.parse(jsonData);

console.log(varArray);
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ffeLtaa6/

any suggestion ?

Comment: I think it's because your JSON starts with a `'`

Comment: @KobyDouek Its directly coming from the db what should i do to conver it into js recognised format ?

Comment: @Vikram backend should send you data in a raw format, but it seems to be encoded by backend first

Comment: Unescape all the things...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have incorrectly wrapped parts of your JSON in quotes

```
[{"pricing":"{\"price\": .... 
            ^
           This shouldn't be here
```

...

```
.... \"standingCharge\": \"y\"}}"}]
                                ^
                               This shouldn't be here
```

Alternatively, maybe you ARE supposed to have that part wrapped, but then you need to properly escape all backslashes within that part, i.e. `\\` instead of just `\`.
In that case, when you do `JSON.parse(jsonData)` you would get objects (inside the array) that all have a single property, `pricing`, with a value that is itself a JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your JSON data has objects enclosed in quotations.

Take the error at position 15; The string up to that point as interpreted by parse() is:
`[{"pricing":"{"`

At this point your parse function is looking for a comma to continue with or end bracket to finish this object.

Now, if you skip down the string to position 3312, you'll see the character sequence `}}"}`. Those last two brackets match up the ones in the very beginning.

The format of your string should be `[{"pricing":"{ ... }"}]` if you want a string under "pricing",  or `[{"pricing":{" ... "}}]` if you want the object representing that string.

Take a look at how the object you are JSON-ifying is being constructed, I get the feeling you may be doubling down somewhere on a `stringify()` function for the parent object members.

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0"
the code was working but this message was shown on console with status 200

in my case i managed to avoid the error message by changing the return type from String to Integer

like this:

```
//before
public String method(){
  //code here
  return "evrything went as expected";
}



//after
public Integer method(){
  //code here
  return 0;
}
```

I think this has something to do with the browser that is expecting to get integers, im gonna update this answer if i discover something else

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).