# How do I pass parameters from angular into my nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to pass the id from Angular in to my "/rating" HTTP-Endpoint, with the following call:

```
apiUpdateRating(id){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/rating', {
            params:id
        });
    }
```

But if console.log my "req.params" in my NodeJs API, I see that it is empty:

```
app.get('/rating',function(req,res){
    res.send('RParam: '+req.params);
});
```

Could anyone tell me where my mistake is? I think I do not pass the id properly in the URL, but don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: This thread has the answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823238/how-to-pass-a-string-parameter-from-angular-ui-to-node-js-backend

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  apiUpdateRating(id: number | string) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/rating', {
      params: { id: id },
    });
  }
```

You need to specify both the key and value of a parameter. `params` is an object containing these key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly this did not work and I got a HttpErrorResponse

Comment: core.js:6479 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/rating?id=1', ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: 'Param: [object Object]'}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/rating?id=1"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/rating?id=1"

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your node.js function. You have maybe formatted your response incorrectly. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44160349/12914833